# Use Calendar to schedule work meetings

Tags: macos, iphone, calendar, ical

I have noticed that when accepting a meeting arranged for my work, the default behaviour is that it gets added to my `Home` calendar, while I want it to be added automatically to the default `Work` calendar.

Is any way to configure the calendar to schedule to a specific calendar the invitations from a certain person, or even better, a certain **email domain**?

Answer (score 1):

Using menu item "Calendar" -> "Preferences" -> "General" you can use the pulldown menu for "Default Calendar" to select `Work`, which should stop new events from showing up in `Home`.

I don't know how to get it to select the appropriate calendar based on any conditions.